# How to solve Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

Tags: hibernate

I am getting an exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: net.codejava.hibernate.Book.

Code

```
public class MainApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    // Check database version
    String sql = "select version()";

    String result = (String) session.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(result);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    Book book = new Book();
    book.setTitle("Effective Java");
    book.setAuthor("Joshua Bloch");
    book.setPrice(32.59f);

    Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session1.beginTransaction();

    session1.save(book);

    session1.getTransaction().commit();
    session1.close();


   // HibernateUtil.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to stackoverflow!) It may be useful to provide more information about the error report (do you get a *stack trace*?). Your code needs four *additional* blanks at the start of each line to appear as one *code block*: mark all of it and use "the `{}`-button in the post editor, or type <CTRL-C>.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
  new String[] { "net.codejava.hibernate" });
```

**Solution 2:**

```
sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(new Class[] { Book.class });
```